# ESP8266 to XAMPP server

Tags: php, get, xampp, at-command, esp8266

Recently I have been trying to work with my ESP. I have set up a server using XAMPP on my laptop. I can access that server using `127.0.0.2`. I know that the content viewed on this page is present in the htdocs folder in XAMPP.

So I have created a folder named TEST in htdocs. The ESP is connected to PSoC and is sending some data at regular intervals to the TEST folder on the server. My question is: what is the IP address that will be needed to connect to the server when I use the `AT+CIPSTART` command on the ESP side?

Is it `127.0.0.2` or some other IP from the router? I have tried sending data to ThingSpeak before and there they provide a ready-made GET request link to send data to the server. What will be the GET request link in my case if the server is created using XAMPP? Please help as I am new to networking. Thank you.
Ok. I wrote a php file which takes value in a variable SAP and writes into a text file which is stored in the ht docs folder. The php code is as follows 
'

```
$content = "SAP ID :".$var1." is present for the lecture \r\n";
echo $content;
echo "<br >";
$status = file_put_contents('attendance_record.txt',$content,FILE_APPEND);
if ($status != false)
{
    echo "Data is written to the file :p ";
}
else 
{
    echo "Data was not written into the file :( ";
}
?>'
```

After then I enable the Xampp server and access this file by using 'http://127.0.0.2/receiver.php?SAP=104' Until this point everything is working fine and the text file is being updated. Now the same thing is needed to be done via AT commands using the ESP. The following lines of code is running on the ESP side.

```
AT+CWJAP="SSID","PASSWORD"
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","192.168.0.104",80
AT+CIPSEND=35
GET /receiver.php?SAP=69 HTTP/1.1
```

Now i'm not getting any updates on the text file. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how exacly would you save the data on the server? In a file or in a database? which kind of data are you sending? You have to make a PHP file to handle the data you are sending, so your "GET request link" depends on how you write the php file.

Comment: I want to send an array of data. On the primary side where my ESP is connected is logging some events and updating an array. After some regular intervals I need to send that updated array via ESP to the server on XAMPP. So for that what kind of php file I will be requiring to make? @XerXeX

Answer (score 1):

172.0.0.2 is the same at calling 'localhost' so you would need your laptop's IP for the ESP to connect to. Depending on your OS you can find that opening your terminal and write `ipconfig`(windows) or `ifconfig`(linux) On a MAC go to System Preferences > Network and your IP is displayed under'Status:'

Comment: And what will be the Get request link that I will need to send via ESP for writing into the server?